# Using variables to get Javascript Object properties?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

```
var classes = {
    English: {
        requirement: 40,
        Eng9: 'English 9',
        Eng9H: 'English 9 Honors',
        Eng10: 'English 10',
        Eng10H: 'English 10 Honors',
        Eng11: 'English 11',
        APLang: 'AP Language',
        Eng12: 'English 12',
        Eng12H: 'AP Literature'
    },
};

for (var subject in classes) {
  console.log('processing subject: ' + subject)
  for (var classtitle in classes[subject]) {
    console.log('processing class: ' +classtitle);
    if (classtitle=='requirement') {
      continue;
    } else {
      console.log('subject: '+subject)
      console.log('classtitle: '+classtitle)
      console.log('classtext: ' + classes.subject.classtitle)
    }
  }
}  

console.log(classes.English.Eng9)
```

I'm starting to learn javascript and my first project is a sort of class sorting thing for my school. I can't figure out how to use variables when getting object properties in javascript. As an example, the console.log at the bottom properly outputs `'English 9'`, but the code above that keeps recognizing `classes.subject` as undefined. For reference I want the output to be something like

```
English 9
English 9 Honors
English 10
```

and so on

I also tried

```
console.log('classtext: ' + classes[subject[classtitle]])
```

and that just outputs `classtext: undefined`

Comment: Use computed property when you want to access property by a variable, i.e. `object[variable]`

Comment: @CodeManiac
I tried I also tried

console.log('classtext: ' + classes[subject[classtitle]])
and that just outputs undefined for some reason.

Comment: can you post the complete class object.

Comment: var classes = {
    English: {
        requirement: 40,
        Eng9: 'English 9',
        Eng9H: 'English 9 Honors',
        Eng10: 'English 10',
        Eng10H: 'English 10 Honors',
        Eng11: 'English 11',
        APLang: 'AP Language',
        Eng12: 'English 12',
        Eng12H: 'AP Literature'
    },
};

Currently this is my entire class.

Comment: You need to use `classes[subject][classtitle]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `classtext` using:

```
console.log('classtext: ' + classes[subject][classtitle])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to figure that out for so long. I kept putting the brackets in the brackets. It makes a lot more sense now.